# Flutter Riverpod: 'read' method and 'timerString' getter not found in BuildContext and CountDownController

Tags: flutter, dart, state-management, riverpod

I'm building a Pomodoro timer app using Flutter and decided to use Riverpod for state management due to its recommended practices for scalable projects. I've encountered two main issues that block my progress:

**BuildContext 'read' Method Error:**

When initializing `_countDownController` in `PomodoroIntervals's` `initState`, I get an error saying:

```
_countDownController = context.read(countDownControllerProvider.notifier);

Error: The method 'read' isn't defined for the type 'BuildContext'.
```

**CountDownController 'timerString' Getter Error:**

Attempting to access timerString from _countDownController results in:

```
if (_countDownController.timerString == '00:00:00') {
   _tabController.animateTo(1, duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300));
}

Error: The getter 'timerString' isn't defined for the type 'CountDownController'.
```

**Attempted Solutions:**

- Checked for correct import of Riverpod packages.
- Searched for similar issues regarding the use of `context.read` in initState, suspecting a lifecycle problem.
- Looked for a missing definition or import for `timerString` but found none.

How can I resolve these errors and correctly implement Riverpod for state management in my Flutter app?

Comment: I believe context.read was a package:provider thing, and not a riverpod thing.  Or if it was a riverpod thing it was eliminated in Riverpod 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's right, because `context` has no such parameter. Here's how to do it (and using `ConsumerStatefulWidget`):

```dart
class PomodoroIntervals extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const PomodoroIntervals ({super.key});

  @override
  ConsumerState createState() => _PomodoroIntervalsState();
}

class _PomodoroIntervalsState extends ConsumerState<PomodoroIntervals> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    ...
    _countDownController = ref.read(countDownControllerProvider);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ref.watch(myProvider); // and here...
    return Container();
  }
}
```

The `ref` instance is available as a field of the `ConsumerStatefulWidget` class

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I made all the modifications you suggested, and everything is working properly. I'm new to using Riverpod, but I believe the logic is correct when using `ref.watch(myProvider);` and changing it to `ref.watch(countDownControllerProvider);`.